# Extracting country names from a column in R

Tags: r

I have a table that includes a column called Place oF Birth (included image), some have just the country and some have the layout city, country.
I need to get both forms of the layout in a column on its own.

I have used the following code
str_match(tate_artists$placeOfBirth, ",(.*)$")[,2}
Which gives the names of the country that are in the format city, country and NA for the the ones that state just the format.
Does anyone know what I can add to the code to show the NAs as the original Place of Birth column?
[image: table format]

Comment: Please don't use images to show data. Use `dput(head(data, 15))` in a code block instead. See [r-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) info.

Comment: The function [tidyr::extract()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html) is probably your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want. First make reproducible data:

```
test <- c("Philadelphia, United States", "Wigan, United Kingdom", "Polska", "Kiel, Deutschland")
nation <- str_match(test, ",(.*)$")[,2]
nation
# [1] " United States"  " United Kingdom" NA                " Deutschland"   
nation <- ifelse(is.na(nation), test, nation)
nation <- trimws(nation)
nation
# [1] "United States"  "United Kingdom" "Polska"         "Deutschland"
```